# MediaFrameReader throws ArgementException when setting MJPG format?

Tags: c#, uwp, mjpeg, mediacapture

I'm trying to get each frame's bitmap from the webcam.

I followed this Microsoft tutorial [Process media frames with MediaFrameReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader#set-the-preferred-format-for-the-frame-source). Some other video formats (YUY2, NV12...) are working fine, but selecting and setting MJPG format will cause `ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'` at `MediaFrameReader.TryAcquireLatestFrame()`.

This is my working code for setting up webcam media source and handling FrameArrived event:

```
private async Task StartReadFrameAsync()
{
    MediaFrameSourceInfo colorSourceInfo = null;
    MediaFrameSourceGroup selectedGroup = null;
    var frameSourceGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();
    foreach (var sourceGroup in frameSourceGroups)
    {
        foreach (var sourceInfo in sourceGroup.SourceInfos)
        {
            if (sourceInfo.MediaStreamType == MediaStreamType.VideoRecord && sourceInfo.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color)
            {
                colorSourceInfo = sourceInfo;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (colorSourceInfo != null)
        {
            selectedGroup = sourceGroup;
            break;
        }
    }

    var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
                VideoDeviceId = deviceId, 
                SourceGroup = selectedGroup, 
                MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu
            };
    var mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
    await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

    var colorFrameSource = mediaCapture.FrameSources[colorSourceInfo.Id];
    var preferredFormat = colorFrameSource.SupportedFormats.FirstOrDefault(format =>
    {
        return format.Subtype == MediaEncodingSubtypes.Mjpg && format.VideoFormat.Width >= 720;
    });
    if (preferredFormat == null)    
         return;    

    await colorFrameSource.SetFormatAsync(preferredFormat);
    mediaFrameReader = await mediaCapture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(colorFrameSource, MediaEncodingSubtypes.Mjpg);
    mediaFrameReader.FrameArrived += MediaFrameReader_FrameArrived;
    await mediaFrameReader.StartAsync();
}

private async void MediaFrameReader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
{
    var mediaFrameReference = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();  // <- throws ArgementException 
    var videoMediaFrame = mediaFrameReference?.VideoMediaFrame;
    var softwareBitmap = videoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;
    //...
}
```

I tested two webcam cameras, they had MJPG format support, and I also checked that previewing MJPG format in a `CaptureElement` control does work. Only `TryAcquireLatestFrame()` in event `MediaFrameReader_FrameArrived` will throw.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong, that `MediaFrameReader` cannot acquire a MJPG frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MediaFrameReader throws ArgementException when setting MJPG format?

Please refer to official code sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/ca74baf5c9e53955e8d749733b8e3e4839afd472/SharedContent/cs/FrameRenderer.cs#L97). *For color sources, we accept anything and request that it be converted to Bgra8*

If you want to set  FrameSource as mjpg for camera, please call `SetFormatAsync` method.

```
 if (format != null && !format.HasSameFormat(_source.CurrentFormat))
 {
    await _source.SetFormatAsync(format.Format);
    _logger.Log($"Format set to {format.DisplayName}");
 }
```

And you could also use above code sample test if your camera support mjpg frame. (my device: logic camera c310 not support mjpg).